# Opening encrypted disk at boot using crypttab and decrypt_gnupg doesn't work

Tags: boot, encryption, gnupg, luks

I have a Volume that is encrypted with a GnuPG pass phrase encrypted key.

I can open it, using manual commands, like this:

```
gpg -d key.gpg | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb2 cryptvolume
```

This works fine.

Also, when I manually use the decrypt_gnupg script provided by cryptsetup, it works fine:

```
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_gnupg /etc/key.gpg | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb2 cryptvolume
```

However, when I enter everything in `/etc/crypttab`, it asks me several times for the pass phrase but doesn't accept it and then aborts…

`crypttab` entry:

```
cryptvolume UUID=bac99915-a0ec-4d57-8fa0-xxxxxxxxxxxx /etc/key.gpg luks,noearly,keyscript=decrypt_gnupg
```

Maybe someone has an idea what could be wrong in my setup?

Comment: Do you use the same keyboard layout during boot and when booted? It might be a problem of actually typing a wrong passphrase due to different keyboard layouts.

Comment: Yes, tried English as well. Actually the Root disc has the same password and works. Difference is only that root disc directly use the password for luks while the data disk uses a gpg encrypted key and the above provided decrypt script.

Answer (score 0):

No solution for this so far.
As a workaround I removed the gpg encoded passphrase and directly entered the passphrase directly into a luks key slot.